# Dell Latitude 620 Blank screen after booting up, running with win 7 ultimate

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, dell-latitude

I'm using windows 7 ultimate in dell latitude d620 and the screen is blank after booting. Can anyone suggest me how to resolve it

Comment: Could be a video driver issue. Have you tried to hit F8 and boot into safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information for troubleshooting here.
Still, here are the steps that you can check:
1) Start Windows in safe mode (F8 when it starts booting). Check if you see the picture
2) Connect external display to D-sub output and check if the image is there
Press Fn+F8 to switch between external and internal display

IF that not help there could be multiple reasons for the issue starting for NVidia GPU chip fail to a OS/drivers issue.

Clarify if you see the picture during OS boot (Windows 7 logo)?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Hardoman: There is not enough information for troubleshooting here.

But I have plenty of experience with Dell lattidude D-series (D600. 610, **D620** and D630). Most of the time you could solve this issue by reconnecting the flat 'cable' between the LCD and the motherboard.